# How to retrieve the content of this div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do retrieve just "square" from content this div?

```
<div class="item">
Blue 
<span>•</span> 
Square
<span>•</span>
Infinite
</div>
```

I tried to use innerText.split(), but i cant figure out how to achieve this,,,

```
var text = $('.item').innerText.split("");
```

Comment: There are multiple mistakes, e.g., "innerText" is not a jQuery method.  See: [jQuery.text](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no jQuery user (any more), so here's what retrieves the text with the DOM API:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.item>span:first-child').nextSibling.textContent)
```

```html
<div class="item">
Blue 
<span>•</span> 
Square
<span>•</span>
Infinite
</div>
```

Here's a version that uses `split`:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.item').textContent.split('•')[1])
```

```html
<div class="item">
Blue 
<span>•</span> 
Square
<span>•</span>
Infinite
</div>
```